# How can I brew upgrade git if I can't get past this javac prompt?

Tags: macos, git, java, homebrew

I'm running into some odd issues with `git` today, so I thought I'd reinstall (or upgrade) it. Install and upgrade run into the same issue.

When I run `java --version` it says I have OpenJDK installed. OK, that works. But when I run `brew install git` (or `brew upgrade git`) I run into this command prompt about `javac`. When I hit "OK" nothing happens.

I have a JDK installed, so why does the OS think I don't? Is there some trick to getting the OS to recognize the JDK?

[image: shot of command line]

The full command line that is hitting this OpenJDK issue is `==> ./configure --prefix=//Users/justin.collum/homebrew/Cellar/gettext/0.21 --with-included-glib --with-included-libcroco --with-included-libunistring --with-included-libxml --with-emacs --with-l`

Clicking on the "More Info" link takes me to a page that tells me that Adobe Flash player page that says "We have retired Flash", so that's worthless.

Clicking on "OK" just doesn't do anything. I've waited a few minutes and there's no output on the screen.

Comment: What makes you think that having the java application is the same thing as having the javac application?  `java` is used to execute compiled java libraries.  `javac` is used to *compile* java libraries.  They are not the same thing.  I *could* figure this out by firing up my macbook but we hates it.. my wild a$$ guess suggestion is that you don't have the JDK, you simply have the JVM.

Comment: "you don't have the JDK, you simply have the JVM" -- did you miss the part where the commands show I have `openjdk` installed? This comment isn't really helpful at all.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas take a look at my answer below, the openjdk apparently includes `javac` (not a surprise, it's a dev kit, not just a runtime)

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently just a misfire message. I had the `javac` app installed already:

```
$  which javac
//Users/justin.collum/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin/javac
```

I just pressed OK and (even though it didn't give me any indication that it was doing so) it compiled and installed fine after a long time with no screen output. Leaving this up in case it helps someone in the future.